# How to insert vector animated or vector gif images in jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have tried using normal image code.

```
Column(modifier= Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(5.dp),horizontalAlignment=Alignment.Centerhorizontally
){ 
Image(
    ImageBitmap.imageResource(id=R.drawable.anim), 
    contentDescription="")    
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there was a lot of API changes lately, some of the animation methods were removed and the `AnimateImageVector` is not in the stable version
to be able to have animated vector you need to import the animation-graphics compose module
to at least  `1.1.0-alpha01`

this is the dependency

```
implementation 'androidx.compose.animation:animation-graphics:1.1.0-alpha02'
```

then use the `animatedVectorResource`

Example:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalAnimationGraphicsApi::class)
@Composable
fun AnimatedImage(){
  val image = animatedVectorResource(drawableId)
  var atEnd by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
  Image(
    painter = image.painterFor(atEnd),
    contentDescription = "Your content description",
    modifier = Modifier.size(64.dp).clickable {
      atEnd = !atEnd
    }
  )
}
```